# Start/Stop IIS site automated as an administrator, which is not a built-in "Administrator"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, iis-7.5, automation, appcmd

There are several ways to start/stop an IIS site, in a way that does not require logon to the system. For example:

**1) Command line via APPCMD:**

```
C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe stop site /site.name:"TestSite"
```

**2) VBS script:**

```
Set oIIS = GetObject("winmgmts:root\WebAdministration")
Set oSite = oIIS.Get("Site.Name='TestSite'")
oSite.Stop
```

Running these under a Windows user that is a member of Administrators group, gives me access denied -related error messages. While creating and deleting sites works fine under the same conditions. This also happens with UAC disabled.

I need to run this script automated, what access permissions should I set and where?

Maybe I could set permissions to my application somewhere in Windows, to run it under the highest privileges?

---

*Windows Server 2008 R2*

Comment: Could `PsExec` be an option ? (works like a charm for me)

Comment: @user2196728 That would work, but would also lead to 2 major security flaws. You have to enable the built-in Administrator account, and you will have to store Administrator login credentials unencoded. Most probably just in plan text format.